# Typescript: Error on function argument when the function can be of multiple function types

Tags: typescript

I've got the following example code:

```
type GetMultipleFunction1 = () => Promise<string[]>; 
type GetMultipleFunction2 = (data: number) => Promise<string[]>; 
type GetMultipleFunction = GetMultipleFunction1 | GetMultipleFunction2;

function test(func: GetMultipleFunction): Promise<string[]> {
    return func(); 
}

function getStrings(data: number): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(['hello', 'hi']);
    }) }

test(getStrings);
```

Why do I get the error (line 6 on `return func()`):

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

I feel like GetMultipleFunction can be of either type 1 or type 2. Type 1 needs no arguments.

How do I need to change my code to get rid of the warning?

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwFkCuAbYBLMKIDEkDsBjDAe3wEYoBeKACgEpqA%20KABQCcSBbdAZwgA8vYO3T4A5gG0AukwDcAKFCRY8ZGkzY8RUvgBM1OgBMAhsBMAuKPiRcARhHaMqLDtz6DhoiTPkKIAB5gJOzAUMrQcIioGFi4BMToZIZR6rFaCbqUAD6q0Rpx2olkeooKAGaZSfjhEMK0lURWqTGa8TrV9FZuPPxCImJSslAA3gpQE1Ds8EjsNY2EDIoAvgoVVcni8ADKAxK8tKbmVjb2jl1snL2ee0MsY5NTM3PWEADul%2078DRs1tNO8EgoABuEAANE8AFYQYiMB6PSYAoGg2iSADkAAsICgUCQ0RDMeg0dJ6IpHst6ApVko6sBaFtgLtvOJeKSgA)

--

Edit: What I want to achieve:

I basically want a function that accepts a function as an argument. In my example `test`. And it should accept a function with an argument and a function without an argument. Is that even possible?

Code example:

```
type GetMultipleFunction1 = () => string[];
type GetMultipleFunction2 = (data: number) => string[];
export type GetMultipleFunction = GetMultipleFunction1 | GetMultipleFunction2;

function test(func: GetMultipleFunction, data?: number): string[] {
    if (data) return func(data);
    return func()  // here should be no warning
}

function getStrings1(data: number): string[] {
    return [`hello-${data}`, 'hi'];
}

function getStrings2(): string[] {
    return ['hello', 'hi']
}

test(getStrings1, 2);
test(getStrings2);
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwFkCuAbYBLMKIDEkDsBjDAe3wEYoBeKACgEpqA%20KAZ2ACd18BzAbQC6AbgBQoSLHjI0mbHiKl8AJmp0AJgENgGgFxR8SALYAjCB0ZUW7Lr0GiIADzAkOwKOOhxEqDFlwFidDJVL2lfOQDFSgAfSW8ZP3lAsiVREQAzSKD8dwh2WkyiPVCfWX8FbIAaKE1tAH49AxMzej1rbn4BKABvESh%20qHR09S0NRg54JA4cwsJaWrHRAagJ4CmZgIZ%20gHptqAALM2hWfZJUNShTfRIoAHcNaY6RAF8RDKzgnngAZU4O1nI81GjSMpnMbT%20ti6vWWq3WUD4AANDigUCQALQAEm6C2eiOqAHJ9ugCcIXm9ZoooF9gL8bDxWEoGBD6YIen0BnDpgiiRBUSQCYTiaTyWI8sBaDS6f9yNUlPRRMBxZKfpCGfKhEA)

--

More specific explanation of what I want to achieve: I'm using Vue3 composition functions in order to extract Get requests. Usually I can just call: `/api/groups/`, but sometimes I need to pass an argument to my get request function: `/api/groups/3/members/` Now number 3 would be needed to be passed as an argument.

Comment: Why multiple types at all? Just make `data` [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters)

Comment: Well I thought about that, but then i get another error: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'. In the last line on test(getStrings). See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiwYFkCuAbGASzD2ADEcA7AYyIkrgF44AKAEwEMYOB+ALjiUcAWwBGwKAEomAPjgAFKBGGEAzsAA8qmFEKUA5gG0AujIDcAKAsAzKrUL0EwbS1s0BGbPiIlydupSSAorKapraugYmcgDeFnAJcFCYOFAMbtQskpYAvlYZAXD6mADKOnr6quxcHAJCYhJBCkoq6lrlUaZwcYlJKWmCwADuzaHqrv4ODCzJqhB4AG7AADR9AFbAtNI9vYmz80sshgDkABbAeHgQx6tnhMfG2fGJOZIWeRYwzjAsxTBlkUq2SAA

Comment: In general I'm fine with data being optional as long as no other errors show up.

Comment: What is the purpose of `test`? Right now it looks to me like the error is perfectly valid: You're calling `func`, but not passing in the data that `func` needs. So the two possible ways to fix it are to 1) pass in the data it needs, or 2) rewrite things so that it doesn't need data. But i don't know how to advise you on that since i don't understand the purpose of the code.

Comment: Make `data` optional in `getStrings` as well https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiwYFkCuAbGASzD2ADEcA7AYyIkrgF44AKAEwEMYOB+ALjiUcAWwBGwKAEomAPjgAFKBGGEAzsAA8qmFEKUA5gG0AujIDcAKAsAzKrUL0EwbS1s0BGbPiIlydupSSAorKapraugYmcgDeFnAJcFCYOFAMbtQskpYAvlYZAXD6mADKOnr6quxcvAJCYhJBCkoq6lrlUaZwcYlJKWmCwADuzaHqrv4ODCzJqhB4AG7AADR9AFbAtNI9vYmz80sshgDkABbAeHgQx6tnhMfG2fGJOZIWeRYwzjAsxTBlkUq2SAA

Comment: I've added a more specific explanation of what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line `type GetMultipleFunction = GetMultipleFunction1 | GetMultipleFunction2;`.

Union of two functions never behave in a way you expect.
It produces a function where argument is intersected type of both function arguments.
See small example:

```js
type Foo = (arg: { age: number }) => void
type Bar = (arg: { name: string }) => void

type Union = Foo | Bar

declare let func:Union

// let func: (arg: { age: number;} & { name: string;}) => void
func()
```

This is by design an this is the safest way to call a union of functions.

In your example:

```js
function test(func: GetMultipleFunction): Promise<string[]> {
    return func(); // < ------ ERROR
}
```

The safest way of calling `func` is providing an argument. It will cover two cases. If you passed a function where argument is not required - it will not make any harm.

I think in this example it worh using function intersection instead union. Like here:

```js
type GetMultipleFunction1 = () => Promise<string[]>;
type GetMultipleFunction2 = (data: number) => Promise<string[]>;
export type GetMultipleFunction = GetMultipleFunction1 & GetMultipleFunction2;

function test(func: GetMultipleFunction): Promise<string[]> {
    return func(); // no error
}

function getStrings(data: number): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(['hello', 'hi']);
    })
}

test(getStrings); // error
```

However, we are getting error in a new place: `test(getStrings); // error`.

This is because `Type '(data: number) => Promise<string[]>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<string[]>'.`

I is hard to make a guess what you are trying to achieve here. `data` argument in `getStrings` is unused.

You can also overload your `test` function:

```js
type GetMultipleFunction1 = () => Promise<string[]>;
type GetMultipleFunction2 = (data: number) => Promise<string[]>;

function test(func: GetMultipleFunction2): Promise<string[]>
function test(func: GetMultipleFunction1): Promise<string[]>
function test(func: (...args: any[]) => Promise<string[]>): Promise<string[]> {
    return func(); // ok
}

function getStrings(data: number): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(['hello', 'hi']);
    })
}

test(getStrings); // ok

test(() => Promise.resolve(42)); // expected error
```

Don't worry that I have used `(...args: any[])`, test function still accept only either  `GetMultipleFunction1` or `GetMultipleFunction2`

**UPDATE**

You can get rid of union function and overloadings at all. Just use rest parameters

```js
function test<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => string[]>(func: Fn, ...params: Parameters<Fn>): string[] {
    return func(...params)  // ok
}

function getStrings1<Data extends number>(data: Data) {
    return [`hello-${data}`, 'hi'];
}

function getStrings2() {
    return ['hello', 'hi']
}

test(getStrings1, 2);
test(getStrings1); // expected error
test(getStrings2);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhgUwM4wDwDEVoAe6EAJhsgBQB0tAhgE4DmGAXMnRAJ4DaAugEpkAXgB8yLAzgQm-UZXDR2%20ADTJa1AA6M6AWzbIACjt1p0DDHgiiB7SdNl9kAb2DJ3yBmbAMUiqDS02gx6GELIAPQRyAgA1sAAvsCgkLCIKExmAMowUjIYAIzYACJ0MHTIRCTkyBBgugBGaAzypGV07KXlQq4ent6%20yDwABgAWaAA2EwgAtAAkzm3lCcNqAOSjcGt8ANyJyf7wSMiZMDl5LABMlD1uHl4wPig8G5PTa%20ub2-vA6FiUp3ODkKakuAj2fxgAOyuWBBXBkWiRE0aFgaFIlQYDAQDF%20mChgNh%20TBOyAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've added a better explanation of what I want to achieve. My 2nd code example is basically the same as in my original code. The test func  decides how func() is called. Maybe I should just make test1() or test2(). But I'm wondering if it's even possible what I want to achieve with a single function.

Comment: @danielmoessner made an update

Comment: I didn't know about Parameters<Fn> that is really interesting. And it works. Thanks

Comment: Take a look here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html